# Rishis, Sadhus performing meditation, penance poses

Tags: practice, yoga, meditation, tapasya

As we watch the Holy epic Mahabharata, we see Sadhus, Rishis and even the asuras performing meditation and penance (Tapasya) poses for years as a example standing on one leg with two hands folded (Namaskar) to please Lord Shiva, Lord Brahma so that they will be offered boons from them.

Realistically and ideally, it is really difficult to perform this meditation pose as we are born as human beings.

How these difficult meditation poses were performed by them?

Comment: @sv. Proving hindu texts to be mendacious/fallacious is not the goal of this site. Respect the beliefs of Hinduism on this site.

Comment: It would be wise to take these as symbolism instead of actual literal physical realities. They were so engrossed and dedicated in the internal meditation that it looked as though they didn't have any external physical limitations. In any case, most mainstream scriptures advise against extreme physical torture. For example, Gita 6.12 says to sit in a comfortable position.